# Typescript beginner - Using system.js module loader with typescript issue

Tags: typescript, module, atom-editor, systemjs

I am trying to learn Typescript & want to  use module loaders (system.js) but I am hitting an error that I just cannot seem to resolve. No doubt i have not configured something correctly. I have 2 files one of which is the module that i am looking to import. I have tried importing variables & classes but the error is always there. If anybody can give me a pointer as to where I may be going wrong I would be very grateful.

[image]

I have 2 files along with an index.html & a tsconfig.json file

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.20.7/system.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('main').then(function(m) {console.log(m)});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.ts**

```
import {anotherName} from './test';

let name: string = "bob";

console.log(name);
console.log(anotherName);
```

**test.ts**

```
export let anotherName: string = "Jeff";
```

**main.js**

```
System.register(["./test"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var test_1, name;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (test_1_1) {
                test_1 = test_1_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            name = "bob";
            console.log(name);
            console.log(test_1.anotherName);
        }
    };
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "buildOnSave": false,
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to tell SystemJs to append '.js' to the module names you are giving it.

```
 System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
```

Comment: This is only true when you are *not* transpiling the typescript directly with SystemJS. Even if you are not package configuration should be preferred to setting `defaultJSExtensions`. That is to say you should set up a package and use the `defaultExtension` setting on the package level with the value `"ts"` or `"js"` depending on whether or not you are transpiling with SystemJS